# Cambiar el color de fondo del head de una webix.window

Tags: javascript, webix

Estoy implementando un diálogo para cerrar la session de usuario, usando las webix. Para ello, uso la siguiente función:

```
const app.login = {
  showLogout: function( ) {
    var win = webix.ui( {
          view: 'window',
          id: 'LOGIN.LOGOUT',
          head: 'Close this session ?',
          position: 'center',
          move: true,
          modal: true,
          width: 450,
          height: 200,
          body: {
            rows: [
              { template: 'Do you want to end the session ?' },
              { cols: [
                  { view: 'button', type: 'danger', value: 'Yes, exit', id: 'LOGOUT.YES' },
                  { view: 'button', type: 'form', value: 'No, continue' }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        } ),

    win.show( );
  }
};
```

Lo anterior funciona bien, y genera la siguiente ventana flotante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera cambiar el color de fondo del `head` de la ventana (la zona del título). Es una ventana *peligrosa*, y me gustaría que la cabecera tuviera el mismo color de fondo que el botón <kbd>Yes, exit</kbd>. Como las `webix` admiten *pieles* (configurables para cada usuario), no puedo generar un estilo fijo, porque podría no coincidir con el aspecto del botón para ese usuario/*piel* concreto.

He intentado obtener el `backgroundColor` del botón, y asignarlo *a mano* a la cabecera, usando el inspector de elementos de las *dev-tools* para obtener los datos necesarios:

```
showLogout: function( ) {
  var win = webix.ui( {
        ...
      },
      head = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webix_win_head' )[0],
      button = document.querySelectorAll('[view_id="LOGOUT.YES"]')[0];

      head.style.backgroundColor = button.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

Pero no he conseguido el resultado buscado. El encabezado de la ventana permanece testarudamente con el fondo blanco.

¿ Como aplico el color de fondo (y a ser posible, el del texto) del botón `danger` a la cabecera ?

#### Edito

La jerarquía de elementos que me muestran las *dev-tools* para la ventana flotante es la siguiente:

```
<div class="webix_view webix_window" role="dialog" tabindex="0" aria-label="Close this session ?" view_id="LOGIN.LOGOUT" style="border-width: 1px; display: none; width: 450px; height: 200px;">
  <div class="webix_win_content">
    <div class="webix_win_head">
      <div class="webix_view" view_id="$template2" style="width: 450px; height: 36px;">
        <div class=" webix_template"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="webix_win_body">
      <div class="webix_view webix_layout_line" view_id="$layout3" style="width: 450px; height: 164px;">
        <div class="webix_view" view_id="$template1" style="border-width: 0px 0px 1px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 450px; height: 134px;">
          <div class=" webix_template"></div></div><div class="webix_view webix_layout_line" view_id="$layout4" style="white-space: nowrap; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -1px; width: 450px; height: 30px;">
            <div class="webix_view webix_control webix_el_button" view_id="LOGOUT.YES" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; width: 226px; height: 30px;"></div> 
            <div class="webix_view webix_control webix_el_button" view_id="$button1" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -1px; width: 225px; height: 30px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta expresión:

```
button.style.backgroundColor
```

Te retornará un string vacío **si el elemento en cuestión no tiene explícitamente** un `background-color` dentro del atributo `style`.

Para obtener el color del botón a partir de su clase css, debes hacer uso de [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Para esto puedes crear una función utilitaria que reciba el nodo del cual extraer los estilos y la propiedad deseada.

```
const getCssRule = (el, prop) => {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(el)
  return style[prop]
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```
showLogout: function() {
  var win = webix.ui({
     ...
  },
  head = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webix_win_head' )[0],
  button = document.querySelectorAll('[view_id="LOGOUT.YES"]')[0];

  head.style.backgroundColor = getCssRule(button, 'background-color');
}
```